# Attaching class labels to a Keras model

Tags: python, keras

I am using the Keras Sequential model to train a number of multiclass classifiers.

On evaluation, Keras outputs a vector of confidences and I can infer the correct class id from that using argmax. I can then use a lookup table to receive the actual class label (e.g. a string).

So far the solution is to load the trained model, and then to load a lookup table separately. Since I have quite a number of classifiers I would prefer to keep both structures in one file.

So what I am looking for is a way to integrate the actual label lookup vector into the Keras model. That would allow me to have a single classifier file that is capable of taking some input data and returning the correct class label for that data.

One way to solve this would be to store both the model and the lookup table in a tuple and write that tuple into a pickle, but this doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: I'd like to know how this is not a built in default behavior. What good is a classifier model without labels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I tried my hand at a solution myself and this seems to work. I was hoping for something simpler though.

Opening the model file a second time is not really optimal I think. If anyone can do better, by all means, do.

```
import h5py

from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import save_model


def load_model_ext(filepath, custom_objects=None):
    model = load_model(filepath, custom_objects=None)
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
    meta_data = None
    if 'my_meta_data' in f.attrs:
        meta_data = f.attrs.get('my_meta_data')
    f.close()
    return model, meta_data
   

def save_model_ext(model, filepath, overwrite=True, meta_data=None):
    save_model(model, filepath, overwrite)
    if meta_data is not None:
        f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='a')
        f.attrs['my_meta_data'] = meta_data
        f.close()
```

Since h5 files do not accept python containers, you should consider converting the meta data into a string. Assuming that your meta data exists in the form of a dictionary or a list, you can use json to do the conversion. This would also allow you to store more complex data structures within your model.

Full usage example:

```
import json
import keras

# prepare model and label lookup
model = keras.Sequential();
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=8, activation='relu'));
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile()

filepath = r".\mymodel.h5"

labels = ["dog", "cat", "automobile"]

# save
labels_string = json.dumps(labels)
save_model_ext(model, filepath, meta_data=labels_string)

# load
loaded_model, loaded_labels_string = load_model_ext(filepath)
loaded_labels = json.loads(loaded_labels_string)

# label of class 0: "dog"
print(loaded_labels[0])
```

If you prefer to have a dictionary for your classes, be aware that json will convert numeric dictionary keys to strings, so you will have to convert them back to numbers after loading.

Comment: Accepting my own answer for a lack of alternatives. If anyone does come up with a better solution I'll accept theirs.

Comment: Same problem i'm trying to solve. but your solution doesn't work for me:
 
```save_model_ext(mod1, filepath = 'test_model.h5', meta_data = {0: 'c1', 1: 'c2'})```

yields an error:
```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

What type does your function expect `meta_data` to be ?

Comment: Hello. You have to use data that can be converted to HDF5. dtype="O" means that your data contains a Python object which apparently is not valid. If I recall, I used python dictionaries without problems. Is that really the code you tried or is the truth more complex?

Comment: I get the same error ('Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent') using a dictionary. (Python 3.5).   Also tried using a list and got "TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U13')"   One way to do it for a list is to encode as a numpy array: f.attrs['my_meta_data'] = np.array(meta_data, dtype='S')

Comment: @Cerno do you have any complete sample or sintax to do this? because I am new in machine learning and wanna save class label inside h5 keras model.

Comment: @slymore Sorry for the late reply, I double-checked and you are right. Not sure my memory failed me or something changed within the h5 lib or python since I last tried it, but you have to provide your label lookup as a string. I extended the original answer by a concrete example on how to do this.

Comment: @sh37211 Thanks for your suggestion. I had some trouble with encoding dictionaries, so I provided an alternative that uses json for encoding and decoding. This should allow using lists as well as dictionaries.

Comment: @aminvincent I added a full example. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Cerno it was really clear and worked well. but is there any way that class label .h5 include column output when export and open in [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)? probably like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKJx8.png

Comment: @aminvincent Sorry, I'm not familiar with Netron, but I suggest you ask in their github issue tracker. This answer was for keras in general, but you are looking for a specific Netron answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to save a "list" of labels in keras model directly. You need to use lambda. You just replace the output of lambda with a string tensor containing your labels. Here is a dummy example of how one can perform an "injection" of labels

```
# assume we get labels as list
labels = ["cat","dog","horse","tomato"]
# here we start building our model with input image 299x299 and one output layer
xx = Input(shape=(299,299,3))
flat = Flatten()(xx)
output = Dense(shape=(4))(flat)
# here we perform injection of labels
tf_labels = tf.constant([labels],dtype="string")
# adding ? dimension to tf tensor
tf_labels = tf.tile(labels,[tf.shape(xx)[0],1])
output_labels = Lambda(lambda x: tf_labels,name="label_injection")(xx)
#and finaly creating a model
model=tf.keras.Model(xx,[output,output_labels])
```

This model now stores the labels and returns them as well. All this mess with tf.tile is necessary because a keras layer of shape (N) is actually a tf tensor of shape (?,N) and we add this ?  dimension to the label tensor.