# Is it possible to save the class/label mapping directly inside a keras model.h5 file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using `model.save()` I am able to save the trained model. However, upon using the model for predictions, I still need to recover the respective class/label mappings `(0: 'cat', 1: 'dog' ... etc.)`. Currently I am saving the `.class_indices` from my `train_generator` and reload it to prepare my test-data to accomplish this. However this is quite inconvenient since it forces me to keep the mapping file somewhere save for future use of my saved `model.h5` file.

Hence, I wonder if there is a simpler way of saving the class information i.e. saving it inside the model file. I can't find any information on this in the keras docs, only this post [Attaching class labels to a Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310448/attaching-class-labels-to-a-keras-model) where someone tried to come up with a 'workaround' but I assume there must be a better way.